# JS OOP - class method calling another class from function

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I was curious about JS Design Patterns and decided to try [this website](https://www.patterns.dev/vanilla/command-pattern),
but on the Command Pattern section I got super confused. You can see the explanation in the link but for this post's sake I have provided a code snippet below.

```
class OrderManager {
    constructor() {
        this.orders = [];
    }

    execute(command, ...args) {
        return command.execute2(this.orders, ...args);
    }
}
  
class Command {
    constructor(executee) {
        this.execute2 = executee;
    }
}

function PlaceOrderCommand(order, id) {
    return new Command(orders => {
        orders.push(id);
        console.log(`You have successfully ordered ${order} (${id})`);
    });
}

const manager = new OrderManager();

manager.execute(new PlaceOrderCommand("Pad Thai", "1234"));
```

I am super confused, I thought I was good at JS but apparently I am not..

The questions in line are:

1. How can you call the manager.execute with only one argument, when in the definition there are two?!
2. Why call the function with new keyword like **new PlaceOrderCommand("Pad Thai", "1234")**
3. How does execute2 call the arrow function when it is just assigned in the constructor?!

all these things are super confusing and seem like magic to me..

Comment: This seems very esoteric, and not very good code design imho. It assumes a bunch of things. It's like writing JS poetry - it exists, and it will technically work, but don't ask another developer to enjoy debugging this web of commands. Keep in mind that in JS, everything is just objects. So even your `class` definitions are just calling a function "constructor" and returning some object. Class constructors return `this`, but a function constructed with `new` could really construct anything and return it.

Comment: That website is stupid. If you remove the `new` keyword from `new PlaceOrderCommand`, nothing changes. That's how you know it's stupid.

Comment: I would split up your research. Look into the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#:~:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%2C%20the,values%20for%20the%20method%20parameters.) itself first, with _multiple examples_ ideally from _reputable sources_ (usually a language/library/framework maintainer). Then look into specific JS implementations. I would not go the route above personally, and there are several different approaches that slightly deviate from the overall "command pattern" (some for better, some for worse, I'd argue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tldr - finding reliable information on the internet is hard

> I am super confused

I would be, if I weren't aware that rampant terrible information is everywhere

### Answers:

1. `manager.execute` only requires a single argument - a command instance (or, alternatively an object that has an `execute2` method that accepts an array of orders). I imagine the people who created this example were probably thinking: "In the future, I could have a command that accepts more parameters and I could make that happen by just passing `...args`"
2. Because the authors of this website don't know what they're doing
3. `execute2` **is the arrow function**. So the manager just calls the `execute2` method on the object that was passed into it with a single argument that is the `orders` array held in the `OrderManager` instance.

### EDIT:

This keeps getting better, take a look at the `CancelOrderCommand` when implemented using the "command pattern". It reassigns a local variable and pretends it does the same thing as when the command pattern wasn't being used.

```
  cancelOrder(id) {
    // modifies instance variable 
    this.orders = this.orders.filter(order => order.id !== id)
    return `You have canceled your order ${id}`
  }


...

function CancelOrderCommand(id) {
  return new Command((orders) => {
    // reassign local variable - does nothing 
    orders = orders.filter((order) => order.id !== id);
    return `You have canceled your order ${id}`;
  });
}
```

This website should be blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and raising the notion there are quite a bit of "geniuses" out there =]